# Is this a better and correct way to code this?

Tags: ruby

The Goal is to create a method that reverse-alphabetizes an array of names of animals.

A book instructs to write the code this way:

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev = false)
  if rev
    arr.sort { |item1, item2| item2 <=> item1 }
  else
    arr.sort { |item1, item2| item1 <=> item2 }
  end
end

animals = ["Alligator", "Cat", "Elephant", "Dog", "Bear"]
puts "#{alphabetize(animals, true)}"
```

However, that code was confusing to me, so I wrote a different code that is simpler. I want to know if this alternative code accomplishes the same goal as the previous code.

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev = false)
  if rev
    x = arr.sort!
    x.reverse!
  else
    arr.sort!
  end
end

animals = ["Alligator", "Cat", "Elephant", "Dog", "Bear"]
alphabetize(animals, true)
```

Comment: I suspect the book instructed you to write the code using `sort` and a block because its author wanted you to learn how to use `sort` with a block, and how to use the `<=>` operator. Your method works, but you didn't learn what (I suspect) the lesson was trying to teach you.

Comment: Using `sort!` mutates the input array, rather than returning a sorted copy of the array. This is probably not desired behavior in real-world usage.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not the same. The first one is non-destructive, but the second one is destructive. If you call `animals` after them, the first one returns the original order, but the second one returns the sorted order.

A better way can be:

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev = false)
  arr.sort.send(rev ? :reverse : :itself)
end
```